# Uncaught ReferenceError: Spinner is not defined on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-spinner

I am using `spin.js` library for loading spinner. Chrome is throwing this error

> [Uncaught ReferenceError: Spinner is not defined on].

And spinner is working fine in all other browsers!

Here is the related code:

```
//Jquery Spinner 
$.fn.spin = function(opts) {
    this.each(function() { 
       var $this = $(this), data = $this.data();
       if (data.spinner) {
           data.spinner.stop();
           delete data.spinner; 
       } 
       if (opts !== false) {
           data.spinner = new Spinner($.extend({
                      color: $this.css('color')}, opts)).spin(this);
       } 
    });
    return this; 
};
```

Any solutions?

Comment: if any code or demo than it will be better to answer

Comment: //Jquery Spinner
$.fn.spin = function(opts) {
  this.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        data = $this.data();

    if (data.spinner) {
      data.spinner.stop();
      delete data.spinner;
    }
    if (opts !== false) {
      data.spinner = new Spinner($.extend({color: $this.css('color')}, opts)).spin(this);
    }
  });
  return this;
};

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem as this and I'm not sure if you are using the same AngularJS, Yeoman Stack that I was using, but the way that I solved it was very simple. I just changed up the orders of the `<script src="...">` so that my `spin.js` is at the very bottom of them. See below for example

Before Fix (Giving Uncaught ReferenceError: Spinner is not defined)

```
<!-- startbuild -->
    <script src="scripts/js/spin.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/admin.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

After the Fix

```
<!-- startbuild -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/admin.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/js/spin.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```